The easy and the hard problems involving independent events
In probability, two events are independent if the incidence of one event does not affect the probability of the other event. Math textbooks often have a problem checking if two events are independent or not. There are two kinds of these problem:
The easy one often consists of two or more independent experiments and they merge the results. For example, toss 2 dice, and check if "The result of die 1 is divisible by 2" and "The result of die 2 is divisible by 3" are independent events. To solve this, students only need to say "Obviously these two dice don't affect the result of each other".
The hard one often has one experiment. For example, toss 1 die, and check if "The result is divisible by 2" and "The result is divisible by 3" are independent events. We know that these two events are independent by comparing $P(A|B)$ and $P(A)$. However, students often say these two are independent events for many reasons.
I know the easy one has many applications, as it is how people model the unaffection of trials and calculate the probability of complex events. Yet I haven't seen the meaning of the hard one problem. Does a mathematical professional need to consider the independent events within an easy sample space? Or is this hard problem just popped out by the teachers and schools to assess the understanding of students about independent events?

Are you asking only about problems coming from applications, or also problems in probability theory? In the latter case, I can think of some examples where it's crucial that events are independent for non-obvious reasons (say, Kolmogorov's 0-1 law).

I would like to ask for the usage of independent variables in case the probability space is not (easy to verify) a product space (just like the hard problem above) in both applications and probability theory. That is: what can we do after knowing they are independent events?

To me, the usage of independent events in the easy example is direct when computing complex probability. But the hard one, I don't see any necessity of knowing "divisible by 2" and "divisible by 3" independent. I can easily write what is AB and calculate P(AB).

For future reference, "dice" is plural.  The singular is "die".  I also don't understand what "the unaffection of trials" means.

@XanderHenderson thank you for the editing. That was my mistake. What I meant when I say "the unaffection of trials" is the assumption that the performance of experiment 1 doesn't affect the performance of experiment 2. Just like throwing a coin and a die.

I always figured the point of these exercises is to show that even if two events turn out to be independent, it doesn't mean that the underlying random variables are uncorrelated / independent.
Kind of like "all squares are rectangles, but not all rectangles are squares."

Some additional clarification at OP's request:
An event is a statement about the value of a random variable.

An example of a random variable is "the number that comes up after rolling a die."

An example of an event is "when you roll the die, the number that comes up is divisible by 2."


In your easy example, we are rolling two separate dice, so we have two random variables that are independent. Of course, events relating to those two random variables will be independent as well because the underlying random variables are independent.
In your hard example, our two events are using the same random variable. Just because the events are independent, doesn't mean the underlying random variable is independent.

Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent normally distributed random variables with expected value $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2.$ Let $\overline X = \text{the sample mean} = (X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$ and $S^2 = \text{the sample variance}$ ${}= \dfrac1{n-1} \left( \left(X_1-\overline X \right)^2 + \cdots + \left(X_n-\overline X\right)^2 \right).$
Then $\overline X$ and $S^2$ are independent. Showing that seems to be an instance of what you call the "hard" problem. It put to use, as follows:
Then statistic $\dfrac{\overline X-\mu}{S/\sqrt n}$ has a Student's t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. To compute the c.d.f. of that distribution, one must rely on the aformentioned independence. Then one can say that the interval whose endpoints are $\overline X \pm A\cdot \dfrac S {\sqrt n}$ is a confidence interval for $\mu,$ where the value of $A$ comes from the c.d.f. of the fraction with the Student's t-distribution.
That's just one of a variety of ways in which the "hard" problem is used.
